# Flutter and Firebase - How do I get data from a reference data field inside a document in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, modeling

I'm learning about flutter and I have a question about cloud firestore and its reference data field, to give you some details, here is what i'm doing

In this example, you can use the data stored in the `clients` collection, which has 4 fields for every document: `name, id, idType and areas`, and you can query the data for name and id with a simple builder, but `idType` and `area` are both a `reference fields`, in other words, the information is stored in another two collections called `areas` and `idType`, if you try the query the data from the reference, for example for `areas`, you get `DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>(areas/area2)`.

[Console output here for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qfo3.png)

So what I really need is: is there any way to use that reference to get the data in the other collection?

[clients collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3C7q.png)

[idType collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx5yq.png)

[areas collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNEhF.png)

Here's my test code:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final clientsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('clients');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: clientsCollection.orderBy('name').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          if (snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
            return Scrollbar(
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final clients = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  print(clients['name']);
                  print(clients['id']);
                  print(clients['idType']);
                  print(clients['area']);
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('data loaded'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text('no active list'),
            );
          }
        }
        return Center(
          child: Text('error'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should be getting back a regular `DocumentReference` field, so you should be able to call `get` or `snapshots` on it to load the referenced document's data.

Comment: Sorry for being kinda slow of this but I would just use `.get()` to extract the data? or should I do a model for manage the get there?

Comment: However you want to get the data is fine. The important thing to realize is that you'll need a separate call to load the data.

Comment: If I try using .get() in the field and instance of `Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>`, I will try looking for a solution but I dont know what do here for now.